# Postman error in Monitoring error: JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, postman, monitor

The Postman runner works just fine but the monitor keeps throwing an error after few successful runs.  When I look at the server logs, it does not show any error in the run and returns successful JSON response.
[Postman Monitor Console Log errror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuKMS.jpg)
Here is the test script used:

```
    var json = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    var err = json.error;
    var stat = json.status;

if(stat == "success"){
    tests["Valid Credentials"] = true;
    tests["Valid API"] = true;
    tests["API is configured"] = true;
    tests["No Intenal Exception"] = true;
    tests["Valid Response"] = true;
}else if(stat == "Invalid credentials"){
    tests["Valid credentials"] = false;
}else
if(responseBody.has("Invalid API")){
    tests["Valid Credentials"] = true;
    tests["Valid API"] = false;
}else
if(err == "NULL"){
    tests["Valid Credentials"] = true;
    tests["Valid API"] = true;
    tests["API is configured"] = false;
}else
if(responseBody.has("Internal Exception")){
    tests["Valid Credentials"] = true;
    tests["Valid API"] = true;
    tests["API is configured"] = true;
    tests["No Intenal Exception"] = false;
}else if(stat == "No Data"){
    tests["Valid Credentials"] = true;
    tests["Valid API"] = true;
    tests["API is configured"] = true;
    tests["No Intenal Exception"] = true;
    tests["Valid Response"] = false
}
```

The response looks like below:

```
    {
"status": "success",
"response": {
    "p_status": "Success",
    "p_status_msg": {
        "entityList": {
            "TotalRecordsPerPage": 1,
            "TotalRecords": 1,
            "Page": 1,
            "TotalPages": 1,
            "CatalogInfo": [
                {
                    "CreditHoursLow": 3,
                    "CatalogDescription": {
                        "CatalogDescription": {
                            "Course": [
                                {
                                    "TextNarrative": "Introduction to Literary Criticism of Spanish,Hispanic, American, French and Francophone Literature",
                                    "TermCodeEnd": 200008
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "LectureHours": 3,
                    "CourseLevelList": {
                        "CourseLevels": {
                            "Levels": [
                                {
                                    "LevelCode": "UG",
                                    "LevelDescription": "Undergraduate"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "EquivalentCoursesList": {
                        "EquivalentCourses": {
                            "Courses": [
                                {
                                    "EquivalentSubjectCode": "SOWK",
                                    "EquivalentCourseNumber": 4150,
                                    "EquivalentSubjectDescription": "Accounting"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "CourseNumber": 9011,
                    "CourseTitle": "Race and Ethnic Relations",
                    "NumberOfTimesRepeatable": 2,
                    "StatusCode": "A",
                    "CreditHoursHigh": 5,
                    "CorequisitesCoursesList": {
                        "CorequisitesCourses": {
                            "Course": [
                                {
                                    "SubjectCode": "ACCT",
                                    "CourseNumber": 9999
                                },
                                {
                                    "SubjectCode": "ACCT",
                                    "CourseNumber": 9998
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "RepeatLimit": 0,
                    "CollegeRestrictionsList": {
                        "CollegeRestrictions": {
                            "Restrictions": [
                                {
                                    "CollegeRestrictionInd": "I",
                                    "CollegeDescription": "",
                                    "CollegeCode": "",
                                    "RestrictionIndDescription": "Include"
                                },
                                {
                                    "CollegeRestrictionInd": "",
                                    "CollegeDescription": "College of Pharmacy",
                                    "CollegeCode": "CP",
                                    "RestrictionIndDescription": ""
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "Department": "SOCI",
                    "ScheduleTypeList": {
                        "ScheduleTypes": {
                            "Types": [
                                {
                                    "AdjustedScheduleTypeWorkload": "",
                                    "ScheduleTypeCode": "L",
                                    "InstructionalMethodCode": "",
                                    "WorkloadMaximumEnrollment": "",
                                    "InstructionalMethodDescription": "",
                                    "ScheduleTypeDescription": "Lecture",
                                    "ScheduleTypeWorkload": ""
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "CourseRepeatable": "RP",
                    "GradingModesList": {
                        "GradingModes": {
                            "Modes": [
                                {
                                    "IsDefault": "Y",
                                    "GradeModeCode": "S",
                                    "GradeModeDescription": "Standard Letter"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "DegreeRestrictionsList": {
                        "DegreeRestrictions": {
                            "Restrictions": [
                                {
                                    "DegreeRestrictionInd": "I",
                                    "DegreeCode": "MBA",
                                    "RestrictionIndDescription": "Include",
                                    "DegreeDescription": "Master Business Admin"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "CampusRestrictionsList": {
                        "CampusRestrictions": {
                            "Restrictions": [
                                {
                                    "CampusCode": "M",
                                    "CampusDescription": "Main",
                                    "CampusRestrictionInd": "I",
                                    "RestrictionIndDescription": "Include"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "LabHours": 3,
                    "CollegeCode": "AS",
                    "ContactHours": 3,
                    "MajorRestrictionsList": {
                        "MajorRestrictions": {
                            "Restrictions": [
                                {
                                    "MajorDescription": "",
                                    "FieldOfStudyTypeDescription": "Major",
                                    "MajorRestrictionInd": "I",
                                    "MajorCode": "",
                                    "FieldOfStudyTypeCode": "MAJOR",
                                    "RestrictionIndDescription": "Include"
                                },
                                {
                                    "MajorDescription": "Speech Pathology",
                                    "FieldOfStudyTypeDescription": "Major",
                                    "MajorRestrictionInd": "",
                                    "MajorCode": "SPBS",
                                    "FieldOfStudyTypeCode": "MAJOR",
                                    "RestrictionIndDescription": ""
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "EffectiveTerm": "000000",
                    "TuitionWaiver": "Y",
                    "CourseAttributeList": {
                        "CourseAttributes": {
                            "Attributes": [
                                {
                                    "AttributeCode": "NLAB",
                                    "AttributeDescription": "Natural Science Lab"
                                },
                                {
                                    "AttributeCode": "NATL",
                                    "AttributeDescription": "Natural Science Requirement"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "AdditionalFees": "N",
                    "PrerequisitiesCoursesList": {
                        "PrerequisitiesCourses": {
                            "Course": [
                                {
                                    "Connector": "",
                                    "LevelCode": "UG",
                                    "MinimumTestScore": "",
                                    "ConcurrencyIndicator": "",
                                    "LeftParenthesis": "",
                                    "SubjectCode": "SOCI",
                                    "TestCode": "",
                                    "CourseNumber": 1010,
                                    "RightParenthesis": "",
                                    "MinimumGrade": "D"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "LongTitle": "Race and Ethnic Relations",
                    "ClassRestrictionsList": {
                        "ClassRestrictions": {
                            "Restrictions": [
                                {
                                    "ClassRestrictionInd": "I",
                                    "ClassLevelDescription": "",
                                    "ClassCode": "",
                                    "RestrictionIndDescription": "Include"
                                },
                                {
                                    "ClassRestrictionInd": "",
                                    "ClassLevelDescription": "Junior",
                                    "ClassCode": "JR",
                                    "RestrictionIndDescription": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "ClassRestrictionInd": "",
                                    "ClassLevelDescription": "Senior",
                                    "ClassCode": "SR",
                                    "RestrictionIndDescription": ""
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "SubjectCode": "ACCT",
                    "Year": "0000",
                    "InstructorApproval": "I",
                    "BillHours": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please help...

Comment: Check your server logs for any kind of errors. HTTP 5XX (or even 4XX) errors specifically. It is possible that your server is not able to handle that frequency of requests.

Comment: can you check your json.err in the console ? you should also have more information about the error if you do console.log(json.description), and if there is a field "exception message" you could also console.log(json.exception.message) which, in my case, often proves to be more precise (though if it's not available it crashes, so do a try/catch)